# Modify the sleep setting of another user's account via root

Tags: 20.04

I'm novice with linux but for my job, I need to change settings (including sleep/hibernation) of another user from the root user.

I work on ubuntu 20.04.

I can't do it directly from this other user because it automatically boots into our software under Chrome and I have no way to get back to the desktop or open a terminal.

Is it possible and how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but how will strongly depend on the desktop environment in use.

Comment: Okay, and what information do you need to tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting